# Is there anything magical/logical/scientific about the number 125 in "The One"?

Tags: the-one

Currently watching *The One* for the nth time in my entire life but as I watched it today, I noticed a small detail that intrigued me. As the Multiverse Authority was about to transport Jet Li to the Hades universe, it was said that he had **123** counts of murder and illegal travel.

Including himself (Bad Jet Li), and the last living parallel self he's about to kill (Good Jet Li), there should be a total of 125 universes that exist in the movie.

*Is there anything magical/logical/scientific about the number 125?*

Comment: Well, it's a nice round number, 5³.

Comment: wouldn't 123 counts of murder *and* illegal travel mean he has killed > 123 people?

Comment: In the course of going after the other Next to Last Jet Li, he whacked a number of people. Might that not also be so in the other places he's traveled to? I haven't seen it in a bit; did they separate out the murder from the travel, or was it one lump sum?

Comment: Okay, they aren't counting all the cops he did in during the last one (Lawless) so hey. It doesn't look like it matters all that much; the film makers aren't really hung up on details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When agent Funsch (Jason Statham) is explaining the whole multiverse business to Law (good Jet Li), he mentions something about how universes are created:

> Every time a massive star dies and becomes a black hole, a new universe is created

He also mentions:

> In this universe you are you, in another you don't exist [...]

Which implies that there are more universes than just the one with Jet Lis in them.

So I'm guessing the amount of kills is just about completely arbitrary, it's the amount of black holes that have been created in Statham's universe that happen to contain Jet Lis.

Comment: Seem to have missed those details.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer they don't really make a big deal out of it, it's just something mentioned quickly so they can move on to Jet Li hitting police officers with motorcycles :)

Answer (score -2):

Actually, there is a very nice [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox) to show that every single natural number (and by extension every rational number) is interesting and special.

For the sake of [contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction), assume one natural number is not interesting or special. Then due to the canonic order of the natural numbers, there must be a *smallest uninteresting and un-special number*. Clearly being the smallest number is something special and quite interesting. Hence, we have established a contradiction and our initial assumption must be flawed. Therefore, every single number is interesting and special.

As a corollary, the number 125 (as well as 123) is quite thrilling and exciting. You can adapt the proof for the classification of your choice.

Comment: So basically, for something uninteresting, we make use some fact that makes it unique, thus making it interesting and thereby nullifying the fact of it being uninteresting? Or something like that?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: Yes, that is the argument. Something that is unique is (by implicit definition) interesting. (Disclaimer: I have no idea what film you are talking about)

Comment: I'll leave this post hanging for more answers. However, your answer's logic is very interesting indeed.

Comment: Such black an white thinking.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I prefer to call it binary ;)

Comment: This is amusing but not an appropriate answer to the question.  It's just a play on words--assuming, incorrectly, that being the smallest uninteresting number is interesting _and_ that this classification can be applied recursively an infinite number of times.

Comment: @RexKerr: It doesn't have to be applied an infinite number of times, since this is not a constructive proof. It's a proof by contradiction, as linked in the answer. I suggest to read that article. Regarding the definition of "interesting"; The argument assumes that a number is interesting if it has some qualities unique to that particular number. That is, a property that does not apply to any other number. Hence, being the smallest uninteresting number makes a number unique and therefore interesting.

Comment: @bitmask - Why go to all that trouble?  `N+1` is the unique number after `N`.  Q.E.D.

Comment: @RexKerr: I added a link to an article describing the presented argument in more detail.

Comment: @bitmask - I understand the argument--though I guess the Wikipedia link could be useful for others--and it's still a silly argument, as the constructive `N+1` proof is much easier, and "interesting" doesn't work the way required.  But the bottom line is that this doesn't really address the question of what is notable about _125_.  It is indeed the first number after the first number after ... the first number after 0, but that's probably not the _most_ interesting thing about it, nor does it suggest why 125 was chosen instead of 82.

Comment: @bitmask do you write lyrics for One Direction by any chance?

Comment: @Kevin: Not that I know of. Why?

Comment: @RexKerr: Being the successor of a natural number is not special, since this is the definition of the natural numbers. You could argue that a number that follows an interesting number is also interesting (and then prove the claim by induction or contradiction), but that is a stronger assumption on the definition of "interesting".

Comment: @bitmask just a joke.  "this number is interesting because it's not interesting" reminded me of their lyric "you don't know you're beautiful.  that's what makes you beautiful"

Answer (score -2):

I think the number 125 was chosen at random and demonstrates critical research failure. 137 (the reciprocal of the fine-structure constant) would have been a better choice and would have shown an understanding of quantum theory.